# Nested dictionary from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I have the following data (see below) in a pandas data frame.

I'd like to covert it into a dict that looks like this:

```
my_dict = {

'AB': { 
        'city1': (0.000000, 0.000000),
         'city2' : (0.100000, 0.200000),
          'city3' : (0.200000, 0.400000)

       }
'BC': { 
        'city4':  (0.300000, 0.600000),
         'city5' : (0.400000, 0.800000),
      }
     }
```

I am aware of pandas' `to_dict()` method but have been unable to coerce it to perform this.

---

```
   iso                city        lat        lng
0   AB               city1  0.000000    0.000000
1   AB               city2  0.100000    0.200000
2   AB               city3  0.200000    0.400000
3   BC               city4  0.300000    0.600000
4   BC               city5  0.400000    0.800000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create column `zipped` by `zip` `lat` and `lng` and then `groupby` with double [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
#python 3 need convert to list
df['zipped'] = list(zip(df.lat, df.lng))
print (df)
  iso   city  lat  lng      zipped
0  AB  city1  0.0  0.0  (0.0, 0.0)
1  AB  city2  0.1  0.2  (0.1, 0.2)
2  AB  city3  0.2  0.4  (0.2, 0.4)
3  BC  city4  0.3  0.6  (0.3, 0.6)
4  BC  city5  0.4  0.8  (0.4, 0.8)

d = df.groupby('iso').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('city')['zipped'].to_dict()).to_dict()
print (d)

{'AB': {'city3': (0.20000000000000001, 0.40000000000000002), 
        'city1': (0.0, 0.0), 
        'city2': (0.10000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001)}, 
'BC': {'city4': (0.29999999999999999, 0.59999999999999998), 
       'city5': (0.40000000000000002, 0.80000000000000004)}}
```

Comment: I might be tempted to use `df['zipped'] = df.apply(lambda r: (r.lat, r.lng), axis=1)` instead here...